# Efficiently reading specific lines from large files into R

Tags: r

I'm surprised by how long it takes R to read in a specific line from a large file (11GB+).  For example:

```
> t0 = Sys.time()
> read.table('data.csv', skip=5000000, nrows=1, sep=',')
      V1       V2 V3 V4 V5   V6    V7
1 19.062 56.71047  1 16  8 2006 56281
> print(Sys.time() - t0)
Time difference of 49.68314 secs
```

OSX terminal can return a specific line in an instant. Does anyone know a more efficient way in R?

Comment: It's inefficient because `read.table` calls `readLines(file, skip)` which actually parses the lines and reads into R, then throws them away. To be more efficient I think you'd have to right some C code that `seek()`d through the connection until you saw enough newlines (and you'd need to using buffering appropriately to be fast)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Well you can use something like this

```
 dat <- read.table(pipe("sed -n -e'5000001p' data.csv"), sep=',')
```

to read just the line extracted with other shell tools.

Also note that `system.time(someOps)` is an easier way to measure time.

Comment: Thanks Dirk. This formula works for me: `dat <- read.table(pipe("sed '5000000q;d' data.csv"), sep=',')`

Comment: Or for a range: `read.table(pipe("sed -n '5000010q;5000000,5000010p' data.csv"), sep=',')`

Comment: Sorry, missed the `p` after the address. Now corrected.  If you know the range, both sed and awk ofter a multitude of choices.

Comment: Well this is old but if anyone's still there, can you tell me why this also ends up being kinda slow? Because using the command line I can get the line immediately but when I send it to R it takes much more time

Comment: Because R reads each line by default (unless you use eg `skip=N` to `read.table()` etc pp).