# Reading a specific line from a huge file *fast*

Tags: r, bigdata

I have a huge comma-delimited file (1.5 Gb) and want to read one particular line from the file in R.

I've seen (many) versions of this question many times, and all suggest something like

```
con = file(fileName)
open(con)
scan(con, what=list("character", "character"), skip=1000000, nlines=1, sep="\t", quiet=TRUE)
```

That works, but it's still extremely slow - we're talking between 20 and 30 seconds to read a single line!

Is there a faster way? Surely there must be a fast way to jump to a particular line...

Thanks a million!

Comment: You can use `data.table` for that!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18235269/efficiently-reading-specific-lines-from-large-files-into-r

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you know anything else about the structure of your file?

If every line/row has exactly the same number of bytes then you could calculate the number of bytes and `seek` to the beginning of the line.

However if the number of bytes per line is not exactly the same for every line then you need to read every character, check to see if it is a newline (or other carriage return, or both) and count those to find the line that you are looking for.  This is what the `skip` argument to `scan` and friends does.

There may be other tools that are quicker at doing the reading and counting that you could have preprocess your file and return only the line of interest.

If you are going to do something like this multiple times then it could speed up the overall process to read the file into a different structure, such as a data base, that can access arbitrary lines directly, or pre index the lines so that you can `seek` directly to the appropriate line.

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply - very useful. By the sound of what you're saying "pre-indexing the lines so that I can `seek` directly to the appropriate line" sounds exactly like what I want to do. The only problem is, my file is on a Windows system, and the documentation discourages the use of Seek in such systems. The database route may be more appropriate in this case - can you suggest any references on how I could store this file as a DB?

Comment: @user1353889, the `sqldf` package has a function `read.csv.sql`.  I believe that there are similar functions in some of the other database packages.

Comment: Thanks so much - will investigate. And for the sake of others reading the question in the future, could you also briefly talk to how one might pre-index the lines for use with seek as you described?

Comment: @user1353889, you could loop through reading each line, then calling and saving the results of `seek` (though not on windows).  But why bother when you can convert it to a database and all that is done for you.